# Six-sevenths of a million this sum I’ll maintain. How is this possible?

Tags: riddle, mathematics

> To a thousand add one, twice fifty and ten,
> Six-sevenths of a million this sum I’ll maintain.

<sub>The above puzzle appeared in the book, “Rational amusement for winter evenings” (1821) by John Jackson.</sub>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is what I think is going on

> To a thousand (**M** in Roman numerals) add one (**I**), twice fifty (**LL**) and ten (**10**) which gives **MILL10** and this looks like "six-sevenths" of the word **MILLION**.

Comment: The fellow certainly appeared fond of rot13(Ebzna Ahzrenyf).